# Export summary of multiple regressions from list

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have a list of multiple regressions completed via this code using the standard dataset `mtcars`.

```
models <- lapply(paste("mpg", names(mtcars)[-1], sep = "~"), formula)
res.models <- lapply(models, FUN = function(x) {summary(lm(formula = x, data = mtcars))})
names(res.models) <- paste("mpg", names(mtcars)[-1], sep = "~")
```

Where I now have a list of multiple regressions against the first column "mpg". From here I am trying to export certain summary statistics such as; intercept, coefficient and r.squared.

I have tried using a loop which I've included below.

```
for (i in 1:length(res.models))
{
  res <- res.models[[i]]
  res_bound <- NULL
  intercept <- res$coefficients[1]
  coef <- res$coefficients[2]
  r <- res$r.squared
  res_bound <- cbind(intercept, coef, r)
}
```

Although this gets me a `dataframe` it only includes the results from the last regression model, a 1 row by 3 column `dataframe`. Furthermore, I would like to have the "terms" of each regression in the table to distinguish between which model I am looking at (e.g. mpg vs cyl or mpg vs hp).

Am I simply missing a step in my loop? The ultimate goal is to `write.csv` the final `dataframe`.

Comment: I would use `lapply` to do what you're trying to do with `for`, then use `do.call(rbind, list)` or `dplyr::bind_rows(list)` to combine the list elements in a single table. Basically, write a function that works for one model, use lapply to iterate it over the models, then combine the results.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, did you ever consider to use `broom::tidy` to turn the `lm`-output into nice dataframes?

Comment: @coffeinjunky I have used that function yes, but it does not output r.squared. That certainly would be nicer to use if r.squared could be included

Comment: `broom::glance` does that, which you could merge back to the dataframe from `broom::tidy`.

Comment: Also, to adress your actual question, in every loop iteration, you have `  res_bound <- NULL`  and then later `  res_bound <- cbind(intercept, coef, r)`, leaving you with `res_bound` only for the last iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in base R:

```
res <- lapply(seq_along(res.models), function(i) {

  data.frame(model = names(res.models)[i],
             intercept = res.models[[i]]$coefficients[1],
             coef = res.models[[i]]$coefficients[2],
             r = res.models[[i]]$r.squared,
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

})

do.call(rbind, res)
```

Output:

```
      model intercept        coef         r
1   mpg~cyl 37.884576 -2.87579014 0.7261800
2  mpg~disp 29.599855 -0.04121512 0.7183433
3    mpg~hp 30.098861 -0.06822828 0.6024373
4  mpg~drat -7.524618  7.67823260 0.4639952
5    mpg~wt 37.285126 -5.34447157 0.7528328
6  mpg~qsec -5.114038  1.41212484 0.1752963
7    mpg~vs 16.616667  7.94047619 0.4409477
8    mpg~am 17.147368  7.24493927 0.3597989
9  mpg~gear  5.623333  3.92333333 0.2306734
10 mpg~carb 25.872334 -2.05571870 0.3035184
```

The reason for `seq_along(res.models)` instead of just `res.models` is so we can also grab the name for the associated slot in the list and drop it into the data frame you're making.

Comment: Nice! If you use `Map`, you can pass the names as a second variable and avoid the indexing.

Comment: This is nice and clean, exactly what I am looking for @ulfelder. This creates a list of `dataframes`, is there a quick way in this function to write the list of dataframes into one .csv?

Comment: No, if you want the whole table in one .csv, you'll have to do that after the `do.call` part where you make a single table.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `purrr::map_df` to apply `broom::glance` to each model and then collect the results into a data.frame:

```r
purrr::map_df(res.models, broom::glance, .id = 'formula')
#>     formula r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic      p.value df
#> 1   mpg~cyl 0.7261800     0.7170527 3.205902 79.561028 6.112687e-10  2
#> 2  mpg~disp 0.7183433     0.7089548 3.251454 76.512660 9.380327e-10  2
#> 3    mpg~hp 0.6024373     0.5891853 3.862962 45.459803 1.787835e-07  2
#> 4  mpg~drat 0.4639952     0.4461283 4.485409 25.969645 1.776240e-05  2
#> 5    mpg~wt 0.7528328     0.7445939 3.045882 91.375325 1.293959e-10  2
#> 6  mpg~qsec 0.1752963     0.1478062 5.563738  6.376702 1.708199e-02  2
#> 7    mpg~vs 0.4409477     0.4223126 4.580827 23.662241 3.415937e-05  2
#> 8    mpg~am 0.3597989     0.3384589 4.902029 16.860279 2.850207e-04  2
#> 9  mpg~gear 0.2306734     0.2050292 5.373695  8.995144 5.400948e-03  2
#> 10 mpg~carb 0.3035184     0.2803024 5.112961 13.073646 1.084446e-03  2
```

You could do something similar with `broom::tidy` for the coefficients, or `broom::augment` for the residuals. Note that broom functions are intended to be called on the models themselves, not the summaries, but you can keep the whole thing in a pipeline, if you like:

```r
library(purrr)

names(mtcars)[-1] %>% 
    paste('mpg ~', .) %>%    # or start with `models` at this point
    map(lm, data = mtcars) %>% 
    map_df(broom::glance, .id = 'formula')
#>    formula r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic      p.value df
#> 1        1 0.7261800     0.7170527 3.205902 79.561028 6.112687e-10  2
#> 2        2 0.7183433     0.7089548 3.251454 76.512660 9.380327e-10  2
#> 3        3 0.6024373     0.5891853 3.862962 45.459803 1.787835e-07  2
#> 4        4 0.4639952     0.4461283 4.485409 25.969645 1.776240e-05  2
#> 5        5 0.7528328     0.7445939 3.045882 91.375325 1.293959e-10  2
#> 6        6 0.1752963     0.1478062 5.563738  6.376702 1.708199e-02  2
#> 7        7 0.4409477     0.4223126 4.580827 23.662241 3.415937e-05  2
#> 8        8 0.3597989     0.3384589 4.902029 16.860279 2.850207e-04  2
#> 9        9 0.2306734     0.2050292 5.373695  8.995144 5.400948e-03  2
#> 10      10 0.3035184     0.2803024 5.112961 13.073646 1.084446e-03  2
#>       logLik      AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
#> 1  -81.65321 169.3064 173.7036 308.3342          30
#> 2  -82.10469 170.2094 174.6066 317.1587          30
#> 3  -87.61931 181.2386 185.6358 447.6743          30
#> 4  -92.39996 190.7999 195.1971 603.5667          30
#> 5  -80.01471 166.0294 170.4266 278.3219          30
#> 6  -99.29406 204.5881 208.9853 928.6553          30
#> 7  -93.07356 192.1471 196.5443 629.5193          30
#> 8  -95.24219 196.4844 200.8816 720.8966          30
#> 9  -98.18192 202.3638 206.7611 866.2980          30
#> 10 -96.59033 199.1807 203.5779 784.2711          30
```

Note you get a few extra variables that can't aren't contained in the summary.